# How to write this file name?

Tags: linux

```
echo 'Text\n' >\*\\'"Text in Here"\'\\*$\?\*\*\*\*\*:)
```

**I want to write that file name but it seems like it's impossible to do with these blackslashes**

Comment: How should the final filename look like?

Comment: Like this `\*\\'"Text"\'\\*$\?\*\*\*\*\*:)`

Comment: Like that: `echo \\\*\\\\\'\"Text\"\\\'\\\\\*\$\\\?\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*:\)`?

Comment: What does the real file name look like? without quoting and escaping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just missing a back slash to escape the last bracket

```
echo 'Text\n' >\*\\'"Text in Here"\'\\*$\?\*\*\*\*\*:\)
```

EDIT: I didn't see you actually wanted all those backslashes in the name. In that case you need

```
echo 'Text\n' >  \\\*\\\\\'\"Text in Here\"\\\'\\\\\*\$\\\?\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*\\\*:\)
```

Comment: Basically i need to escape each backslash so it becomes visible in the file name? is that how it works?

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother trying to escape individual characters.  Limit the special characters you need to worry about by using single quotes.  Then, the single quote is the only character you need to worry about, and you get it by enclosing it in double quotes.  Eg:

```
echo 'Text\n' > '\*\\'"'"'"Text in Here"\'"'"'\\*$\?\*\*\*\*\*:)'
```

Better yet, choose a simpler name. :)